# How can I send two different values through axios api to my backend in one request?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I have a backend out of a spring boot application with REST, with a one to many mapping. I want to assign to Patient the caregiver, for that I need to send both id's so that I can find the elements. Frontend is react js and axios

the react page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CaregiverApiService from "../../service/CaregiverApiService";

class AddRelationCaregiverPatient extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
        idPac:'',
        idCare:'',
                       message: null
        }
        this.getOne = this.getOne.bind(this);
    }

    getOne = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let rel = {idPac: this.state.idPac, idCare: this.state.idCare};
            console.log(rel);
               const { idPac, idCare } = this.state;
CaregiverApiService.getOne(idPac,idCare)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({message : 'Caregiver added successfully.'});
                this.props.history.push('/patients');
            });
    }

    onChange = (e) =>
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h2 className="text-center">Add Caregiver</h2>
                <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Caregiver Name:</label>
                    <input type= "number" placeholder="idPac" name="idPac" className="form-control" value={this.state.idPac} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Surname:</label>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="idCare" name="idCare" className="form-control" value={this.state.idCare} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                </div>
                <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.getOne}>Save</button>
            </form>
    </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddRelationCaregiverPatient;
```

The api request I tried to make

```
  getOne(idPac,idCare)
    {
    return axios.put(CAREGIVER_PACIENT_API_BASE_URL+'/'+idCare+ '/'+idPac);
    }
```

The backend

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/caregiver_patient")
public class caregiver_patientController {
    @Autowired
    private CaregiverService careService;

    @Autowired
    private PatientService patService;
    @PutMapping("/{id}/{id}")
    public ApiResponse<Patient> getOne(@PathVariable int idCare,@PathVariable int idPat){
       PatientViewDTO pp= patService.findPatientByIdPatient(idPat);
        CaregiverViewDTO cc=careService.findCaregiverByIdCaregiver(idCare);
        pp.setCaregiver_idCaregiver(CaregiverViewBuilder.generateEntityFromDTO(cc));
        Patient pat=PatientViewBuilder.generateEntityFromDTO(pp);
        PatientDTO ppat= PatientBuilder.generateDTOFromEntity(pat);
        patService.update(ppat);
        return new ApiResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK.value(), "Patient fetched successfully.",ppat);
    }
//



}
```

I get the error and I can't figure out a solution to this
"HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.
(XHR)OPTIONS - http://localhost:8080/caregiver-patient/[object Object]/[object Object]"
Thank you!

Comment: your `@GetMapping("/{id}/{id}")` listed the same parameter twice, give them unique names, e.g. `@GetMapping("/{idCare}/{idPat}")`. Also, idCare and idPac are objects in your JS code, which obviously are searialized to [object] instead of an integer

Comment: good point, i changed them to coresponding values and i get a 403

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue at this line:
`CaregiverApiService.getOne(idPac,idCare)`

A few lines above `idCare` declared as object: `{idCare: this.state.idCare}`.

As result, the url contains `[object Object]`.

Have you tried that:

```
const { idPac, idCare } = this.state;
CaregiverApiService.getOne(idPac, idCare)
```

?

Comment: I did, I get the error : "HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
(XHR)OPTIONS - http://localhost:8080/caregiver-patient/1/1"

Comment: On backend you have GET mapper, but from client you send PUT request: `axios.put`. Try to change to `axios.get`. Or use `@PutMapping` on backend, depending on your needs.

Comment: Updated, I get : "SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'http://localhost:3000' did not find 'http://localhost:3000' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for cross-origin  resource at 'http://localhost:8080/caregiver_patient/1/1'.

HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR)GET - http://localhost:8080/caregiver_patient/1/1"

Answer (score 0):

To fix your CORS exception while developing, just add `app.security.allow-all-origins = true` to your `application-dev.properties` or allow all origins with:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

Not answering the question, more a general advice: Figuring out the problem a spring boot server has with a request is really annoying without an ExceptionHandler.

Add this to your project to make your life better:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public void handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        log.warn("Returning HTTP 400 Bad Request for invalid http message", e);
    }
}
```